# float64 to float32 Cython Error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

I've created a Cython code to make matrix operations between a dense matrix and a sparse vector,as follows (as I'm learning Cython I'm not sure this is a good code, but it's the best I could come up with so far):

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
ctypedef np.float64_t dtype_t
ctypedef np.int32_t dtypei_t
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
def cdenseXsparse(np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim = 2] Y,
                  np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim = 1] V,
                  np.ndarray[dtypei_t, ndim = 1] I,
                  np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim = 1] A = None):
    """
    Computes A = Y * (V_I)
    """
    if Y is None:
        raise ValueError("Input cannot be Null")
    A = np.zeros(Y.shape[1])
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, indice
    cdef dtype_t s  
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):             
        s = 0
        for indice in range(len(I)):
            s += Y[I[indice], i] * V[indice]
        A[i] = s
    return A
```

It works fine. But when I change the third line from:

```
ctypedef np.float64_t dtype_t
```

to:

```
ctypedef np.float32_t dtype_t
```

and compile the .pyx file and run again the matrix operations I get the error:

```
"Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'dtype_t' but got 'long'"
```

As an example, when compiling using np.float32_t and running the code:

```
In [3]: from numpy import random as rd, array, int32, float32

In [4]: y = array(rd.rand(10, 200), dtype = float32)

In [5]: v = array([1, 2, 3], dtype = float32)

In [6]: i = array([0, 1, 2], dtype = int32) 

In [7]: from cdenseXsparse import cdenseXsparse

In [8]: r = cdenseXsparse(y, v, i)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-319f9c8c8d49> in <module>()
----> 1 r = cdenseXsparse(y, v, i)

/home/will/workspace/s3_RecSys/SVD/cdenseXsparse.so in cdenseXsparse.cdenseXsparse     (cdenseXsparse.c:1484)()

ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'dtype_t' but got 'double'
```

Is there a different way to use float32 in Cython? Using float64 and float32 shouldn't work the same way?

For what I've researched so far it should work the same, but it didn't in that code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have to use  `dtype = float64` in your Python code, or change the Cython code to `np.float32_t`. But you cannot mix single and double precision...

Comment: Hi Saullo. When I use float64 in my code it works fine. The problem is when I try to convert it to float32. It does not accept the conversion.

Comment: did you try this: `ctypedef np.float32_t dtype_t` in your Cython code when you use `float32`?

Comment: Yes, but it does not work...

Comment: I have a sample code here where I used: `ctypedef np.float_t dtype_t`... without the `32`... for single precision, maybe that will work for you, but I don't know the reason why `float32_t` did not work for me...

Comment: The reason I'm trying to use 32 bits is to make faster computations with the matrices

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37953/discussion-between-saullo-castro-and-will)

Comment: Will, very trivial question. Have you restarted your python/ipython console after compiling?

Comment: yes, I did. Still didn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default behaviour of np.zeros is to create a float64 data, if you want to force the datatype to be float32 you should specify it. You should also put all cdefs in the beginning of the function.

Comment: I tried to initialize the A matrix such as `A = np.zeros(Y.shape[1], dtype = np.float32)` and `A = np.zeros(Y.shape[1], dtype = dtype_t)` but either case led to the same error. Am I doing something wrong? Tnx =)!

Comment: Nvm, it worked! I recently tried it again and now it worked, I probably messed up on something I'm not aware of, but making the matrix A such as `A = np.zeros(Y.shape[1], dtype = np.float32)` went fine now! Thanks a lot!